# google sign in with fresh account not working | exiting sign in intent

Tags: android, google-signin

I have followed every single step mentioned on the google doc (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) for integrating the google sign in but every time I tried to use the service am getting following errors

1. Fresh account: Am able to add new account but while coming back from google account creation app the google intent exit and am forced to click the google sign in again then it work as expected
2. Choose a google account then immediately the sign in activity exit and when I click the sign in button again this time app automatically do the sign in ... no account chooser
3. GooglePlayServiceAvaialblity exception : In some phone am getting this exception don't know how to handle this ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: facing the same issue. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, tried many things nothing worked out. Now I have disabled that feature

Comment: lol! I thought Google would be more sophisticated than this but I was wrong again. I have given up as well after wasting quite a bit of time. Thanks for the response :)